# Shipping options

Tags: shipping, option

I am looking to create different shipping options for HI, AK as compared to the rest of the States.  For HI, AK I want to charge $15 a shipment and ship USPS.  For the rest of the states I want to charge a flat rate.  When I set up a table for AK, HI and test an order to one of these states I get the option of the flat rate fee and USPS rate of $15 I only want the $15 rate to show up for these states.  How would I do this?  I would also like to add a pick up order option.
Any suggestions on plugins that would handle this?